# Translate Front-End Site Interface in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, translation

I am working on a multi-lingual website in Drupal 7. I installed the i18n module to translate the content on the website. However, I also have other site interface elements on the front-end part of the website like button texts, navigation links, etc that I would like to translate.

Is it really necessary to develop different themes per language? Or is there a more elegant solution to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is it really necessary to develop different themes per language?"

No, it isn't. Every visual text can be translated, via the **Translate interface**-entry in the admin menu. If you write your own modules, templates and stuff, use the t-function to make the terms available in **Translate interface** or write your own po-files.

There is one issue of course: if the length of the terms in language A is too different to language B you can get in trouble with your layout. So test everything in depth and load different css styles if necessary.